# spring boot application according to ldap groups

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, authorization

I 'm using ldap authentication to secure a spring boot app. I want to authorize endpoints for specific groups of ldap server. Any suggestions?

Here's my SecurityConfig.java file.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/403","/login","/footer").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/","/LifeForm**","/home").fullyAuthenticated()
            //.anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            //.httpBasic()
            //.and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/403").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/403").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(ldapEnabled)) {

        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))")
                .groupRoleAttribute("cn")
                .groupSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member={0}))")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls + ldapBaseDn)
                .managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal)
                .managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword);

    } else {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this working? I am struggling with the same problem now and my LDAP config is similar to yours but my groups aren't mapping to authorities? Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a "antMatcher" that verifies one authority in Ldap.

For example:

```
.antMatchers("/admins").hasAuthority("GROUP-SPAIN")
```

I have this configuration in my application

```
 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/v2/api-docs",           // swagger
                        "/webjars/**",            // swagger-ui webjars
                        "/swagger-resources/**",  // swagger-ui resources
                        "/configuration/**",      // swagger configuration
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**/*", "/management/*.json").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admins").hasAuthority("GROUP-SPAIN"")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

You need to create a UserDetailsService class for add the authorities that you need instead of user group. In the example, i use the data base as example, you need to change my userDao for your ldap conection.

```
    @Component
public class TodoListUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao; //Change for ldap conection

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //Get the user from ldap.
        AppUser user = userDao.findByUsername(username);

        if (null == user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Username {0} doesn't exist", username));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        //this part is pseudocode
        user.getGroups().forEach(ldapGroup -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ldapGroup.toString()));
        });

        UserDetails userDetails = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Spring will use your UserDetailsService when a user try to access to the application.

Comment: Yes but this is about roles not groups.right? I don't know role names in my Ldap server. I want to authorize my app according the group name